# bitmap not showing

Tags: java

`file.name = "/sdcard/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot_2013-01-15-10-42-02.jpg";`

however, every time i try to open the file by clicking the bitmap, it causes the opening application to crash, not my application. also, the bitmap doesn't show the image somehow.

Adapter.java (to bitmap)

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, Viewgroup parent(){
   case Image:
   Bitmap bp = new BitmapFactory().decodeFile(file.name);
   image.setImageBitmap(bp.createBitmap(200,200,Config.ARGB_8888));
   break;

}
```

my dialog displays directory "/sdcard" and all its files. 
upon selecting the file/image, the path is saved along with the bitmap image.

(eg: `file.name = "/sdcard/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot_2013-01-15-10-42-02.jpg";`)
 also, the bitmap doesn't show the image somehow.

i have set the write external storage permission. and code snippet are as below. i have really no idea what's going wrong. i also have tried all file types, such as txt, pdf, doc, etc, all causing the open file application to crash, and not opening the file.

Adapter.java (to bitmap)

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, Viewgroup parent(){
   case Image:
   Bitmap bp = new BitmapFactory().decodeFile(file.name);
   image.setImageBitmap(bp.createBitmap(200,200,Config.ARGB_8888));
   break;

}
```

Comment: @StefandeBruijn just did

Comment: ...Is there anything else?  Since it's not your app that's crashing, make sure you set the filter to not just display events for your app.

Comment: @j__m sadly that's it! actually when i click on my bitmap image, there's nothing from the dialog at all. the log is generated for my gridview that displays the bitmap, i think.

Comment: if there's no logcat output from the other app, and the file exists... i'm not sure what to do after that lol.

Comment: @j__m how can i see the log from other apps? say if i use the system gallery to open my img file, and system gallery crashes, how can i set the filter? it seems currently i have set logcat to "verbose", and it shows everything...

Comment: If you're in Eclipse, the logcat window has a "Saved Filters" pane, which should be set to "All messages (no filters)".  This is separate from the debug/warning/error etc. filtering.

Comment: If you're not in Eclipse, then I don't know offhand.

Comment: @j__m your answer helps with the bitmap! But clicking the bitmap and trying to open the file still causes othe apps to crash, and the file was never open!

Comment: the other part of your question is still impossible to answer unless you give us _something_ to work with.  i suggest you remove that part of the question and accept the answer.  if you later find any scrap of information about the other activity that you can share with us, open a new question.

Comment: Well the source code of Gallery.java is online for troubleshooting; question is, what exact version of Android did this logcat come from? (4.0.4r2.1, etc.)

Comment: @j__m i have created a new post for that question. android sdk? i'm using 3.0 +, and the testing device is samsung galaxy android 4.1 i believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I just noticed your comment that "the bitmap doesn't show the image somehow."

Change

```
image.setImageBitmap(bp.createBitmap(200,200,Config.ARGB_8888));
```

to

```
image.setImageBitmap(bp);
```

`createBitmap()` creates a blank bitmap.  It does not resize an existing bitmap.

There are a few different ways to resize an existing bitmap.  For example, you can use:

```
image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bp, 200, 200, true));
```