# Error reading file on Sdcard

Tags: java, android, io

My dialog displays directory `/sdcard` and all its files. Upon selecting the file/image, the path is saved along with the bitmap image, e.g.

```
file.name = "/sdcard/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot_2013-01-15-10-42-02.jpg";`
```

However, every time i try to open the file by clicking the bitmap, it causes the opening application to crash, not my application.

I have set the write external storage permission. Code snippet as shown below. I have really no idea what's going wrong. I also tried all file types, such as `txt`, `pdf`, `doc`, etc., all causing the open file application to crash, and not opening the file.

**Adapter.java** (to bitmap)

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, Viewgroup parent(){
   case Image:
   Bitmap bp = new BitmapFactory().decodeFile(file.name);
   image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.create(bp, 200, 200, true));
   break;

}
```

**Activity.java**

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(new File(file.name)));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

  switch(file.getTypeByName()){
  case Image:
       intent.setType("image/*");
       break;
  }
 startActivityforResult(intent, 000);
}
```

**Logcat**

```
04-10 12:04:42.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4513): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 12:04:42.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4513): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.sec.gallery3d/com.android.sec.gallery3d.app.Gallery}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-10 12:04:42.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1968)
04-10 12:04:42.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
04-10 12:04:42.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
04-10 12:04:42.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
04-10 12:04:42.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 12:04:42.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-10 12:04:42.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
04-10 12:04:42.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 12:04:42.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-10 12:04:42.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:978)
04-10 12:04:42.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
04-10 12:04:42.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 12:04:42.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4513): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-10 12:04:42.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at com.android.sec.gallery3d.app.Gallery.startViewAction(Gallery.java:377)
04-10 12:04:42.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at com.android.sec.gallery3d.app.Gallery.initializeByIntent(Gallery.java:237)
04-10 12:04:42.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at com.android.sec.gallery3d.app.Gallery.onCreate(Gallery.java:149)
04-10 12:04:42.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4469)
04-10 12:04:42.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
04-10 12:04:42.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
04-10 12:04:42.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     ... 11 more
04-10 12:04:42.164: W/ActivityManager(668):   Force finishing activity r.intent.getComponent().flattenToShortString()
04-10 12:04:42.234: E/android.os.Debug(668): !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -n -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
04-10 12:04:42.244: I/dumpstate(4530): begin
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException . Debug you code and you found error.

Comment: If we're gonna dig into Gallery.java, we're gonna need the exact version of Android this is from.  Go to Settings -> About device and report the exact Android version.

Comment: @j__m it's 4.0.4 on the device.

Comment: This is a dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929203/bitmap-not-showing

Comment: No, he had two different questions.  One was answered.  This is a followup.

Comment: @BrettDuncavage i haven't had the time to edit the earlier post yet... this is a different question. thank you!

Comment: @j__m it's not a he... it's a she! thanks

Comment: That was actually uncharacteristic of me. I usually call everyone a "she" despite the fact that statistically I'm usually wrong. = )

Comment: Oh, sorry. The text was almost the same from both questions.

Comment: @j__m i couldn't find the package of "com.android.sec.gallery3d.app.Gallery.java" , i only found "com.android.gallery3d.app.Gallery.java" :(

Comment: you're right; i missed that.  the "sec" version is samsung's private alterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3677598/1704011 answer

To quote a commenter:

> using setDataAndType() instead of the 2 separate calls fixed her
>   issue.

That really confused the hell out me why that would be necessary. Then I looked at the implementation of `Intent.setType()`, `Intent.setData()`, and `Intent.setDataAndType()`. And look at this:

```
public Intent setType(String type) {
    mData = null;
    mType = type;
    return this;
}

public Intent setData(Uri data) {
    mData = data;
    mType = null;
    return this;
}
```

So a call to `setType` after `setData` clobbers the data and a call to `setData` clobbers the type. That's why the gallery app is breaking, you `setType` after `setData` so when the intent is sent the data is null. Granted the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setType%28java.lang.String%29) do mention this behavior, but it is not intuitive based on the method names, something like `setTypeOnly` and `setDataOnly` seems more explicitly convey the purpose of those methods. Otherwise it is unclear that these methods are mutually exclusive.

Use `setDataAndType()` and that should fix your issue.

Comment: This seems really bizarre to me, but hey - programming is the art of what works, not what seems like it ought to work.  +1 for digging that up.

Comment: I agree, this shouldn't be necessary. I'll be interested if it solves the issue in the poster's case.

Comment: Forget shouldn't be necessary - having never seen the internal implementation of the Uri class, I wouldn't expect that to work at all.  Now I've glanced at the source code, and it makes me never want to use the Uri class again!

Comment: sorry i was talking to coworkers.. but the above answer is not working for me. i tried it this way, and believe it or not, Uri.fromFile gives the Uri in a "file:///sdcard/downloads/filepath.ext" format also..